# SNTP, why do you mock me?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ntp

--- SOLVED SEE EDIT 5 ---

My w2k3 pdc is configured as an authoritative time server. Other servers on the domain are able to sync with it if I manually specify it in the peer list. By if I try to sync from flags 'domhier', it wont resync; I get the error message

```
The computer did not resync because no time data was available.
```

I can only think that it is not querying the pdc. I also tried setting the registry as shown here (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193825). But no luck (I have not restarted the server, I am hoping I wont have to since it is the pdc)

If you would like any further information on my config, please let me know.

---

**Edit 1:**

I have set the w32time service config AnnouceFlags to 0x05 as documented here [www.krr.org/microsoft/authoritative_time_servers.php](http://www.krr.org/microsoft/authoritative_time_servers.php) and a number of other places.
The PDC syncs to an external time source (ntp).

I can get the stripchart on the client from the pdc no problems.

The loginserver for the host I am trying to configure is shown as the pdc.

---

**Edit 2:**

The packet capture has revealed something interesting. The client is contacting the correct server, and getting a valid response but I still get the same error message.

Here is the NTP excerpt from the client to the server

```
Flags:
    11.. .... = Leap Indicator: alarm condition (clock not synchronized) (3)
    ..01 1... = Version number: NTP Version 3 (3)
    .... .011 = Mode: client (3)
Peer Clock Stratum: unspecified or unavailable (0)
Peer Polling Interval: 10 (1024 sec)
Peer Clock Precision: 0.015625 sec
Root Delay: 0.0000 sec
Root Dispersion: 1.0156 sec
Reference Clock ID: NULL
Reference Clock Update Time: Sep 1, 2010 05:29:39.8170 UTC
Originate Time Stamp: NULL
Receive Time Stamp: NULL
Transmit Time Stamp: Nov 8, 2010 01:44:44.1450 UTC
Key ID: DC080000
```

Here is the reply NTP excerpt from the server to the client

```
Flags: 0x1c
    00.. .... = Leap Indicator: no warning (0)
    ..01 1... = Version number: NTP Version 3 (3)
    .... .100 = Mode: server (4)
Peer Clock Stratum: secondary reference (3)
Peer Polling Interval: 10 (1024 sec)
Peer Clock Precision:  0.00001 sec
Root Delay: 0.1484 sec
Root Dispersion: 0.1060 sec
Reference Clock ID: 192.189.54.17
Reference Clock Update Time: Nov 8,2010 01:18:04.6223 UTC
Originate Time Stamp: Nov 8, 2010 01:44:44.1450 UTC
Receive Time Stamp: Nov 8, 2010 01:46:44.1975 UTC
Transmit Time Stamp: Nov 8, 2010 01:46:44.1975 UTC
Key ID: 00000000
```

---

**Edit 3:**

dumpreg for paramters on pdc

```
Value Name      Value Type          Value Data
------------------------------------------------------------------------

ServiceMain     REG_SZ              SvchostEntry_W32Time
ServiceDll      REG_EXPAND_SZ       C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll
NtpServer       REG_SZ              bhvmmgt01.domain.com,0x1
Type            REG_SZ              AllSync
```

and config

```
Value Name                Value Type          Value Data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

LastClockRate             REG_DWORD           156249
MinClockRate              REG_DWORD           155860
MaxClockRate              REG_DWORD           156640
FrequencyCorrectRate      REG_DWORD           4
PollAdjustFactor          REG_DWORD           5
LargePhaseOffset          REG_DWORD           50000000
SpikeWatchPeriod          REG_DWORD           900
HoldPeriod                REG_DWORD           5
LocalClockDispersion      REG_DWORD           10
EventLogFlags             REG_DWORD           2
PhaseCorrectRate          REG_DWORD           7
MinPollInterval           REG_DWORD           6
MaxPollInterval           REG_DWORD           10
UpdateInterval            REG_DWORD           100
MaxNegPhaseCorrection     REG_DWORD           -1
MaxPosPhaseCorrection     REG_DWORD           -1
AnnounceFlags             REG_DWORD           5
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset     REG_DWORD           300
FileLogSize               REG_DWORD           10000000
FileLogName               REG_SZ              C:\Windows\Temp\w32time.log
FileLogEntries            REG_SZ              0-300
```

---

**Edit 4:**

Here are some notables from the ntp log file on the pdc.

```
ReadConfig: failed. Use default one 'TimeJumpAuditOffset'=0x00007080
DomainHierachy: we are now the domain root.
ClockDispln: we're a reliable time service with no time source: LS: 0, TN: 864000000000, WAIT: 86400000
```

---

**Edit 5:**

***F&^%ING SOLVED!*** Ok so I was reading about people with similar problems, some mentioned w32time server settings applied by GPO, but I tested this early on and there were no settings applied to this service by gpo. Others said that the reporting software may not be picking up some old gpo settings applied. So I searched the registry for all w32time instaces. I came across an interesting key that indicated there may be some other ntp software running on the server. Sure enough, I look through the installed software list and there the little F*&%ER is. Uninstalled and now working like a dream.

***FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUU***

Comment: How did you generate the ntp request in the catpure? I means `net time` or `w32tm`? And parameters?

Comment: I used 'w32tm /resync'

Comment: What was the other NTP software?

Comment: I didn't think to note that. I forget now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I was reading about people with similar problems, some mentioned w32time server settings applied by GPO, but I tested this early on and there were no settings applied to this service by gpo. Others said that the reporting software may not be picking up some old gpo settings applied. So I searched the registry for all w32time instaces. I came across an interesting key that indicated there may be some other ntp software running on the server. Sure enough, I look through the installed software list and there the little F*&%ER is. Uninstalled and now working like a dream.

Answer (score 4):

I always follow this setup, never had any issues.

On the PDC for the Domain:

`w32tm /config /manualpeerlist: "peers" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update`

Get peers from [here](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html).

On all the servers and in login scripts (or you can use Group Policy):

`w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update`

`Net Stop w32tm`

`Net Start w32tm`

Reference:

Configure w32tm on PDC: [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786897(WS.10).aspx)

Configure w32tm on computers: [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758905(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: I'll go back and try this.

Comment: Just out of interest, what settings do you apply to workstation pcs?

Comment: @Matthew - the second section gets added to the domain login script(s) so that it runs on all desktops.  (I think you need to set the NTP servers, the one you have set in the Registry doesn't look valid, which would invalidate your PDC as a time server.)

Comment: Ah that points to a linux server which hosts a few services. It is running an NTP server. Maybe there is a problem with how I have that configured.

Comment: shouldn't the w32tm /resync command work on the pdc after these changes?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your PDC has a valid external time source. If not, it may be flagging itself as 'unreliable' and clients may back off.

Also check that you can run **w32tm /stripchard /computer:yourdcnamehere** from a client and receive a valid response.

Lastly, the domain time sync heirachy isn't consistently documented by microsoft, but I believe your clients will checking in with their **logon server** for time sync. That may or may not be the PDC depending on your topology. So verify on the clients that doing a **echo %logonserver%** returns the PDC's name.

BTW, as of 2003 and XP, you're dealing with a full NTP implementation rather than the stripped-down 2000-and-earlier SNTP. **net time** is deprecated and **w32tm** should be used for configuration. Again, this isn't clearly documented IMO.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried all this I think. I have set the w32time service config AnnouceFlags to 0x05 as documented here http://www.krr.org/microsoft/authoritative_time_servers.php and a number of other places. I can get the stripchart on the client from the pdc no problems. The loginserver for the host I am trying to configure is shown as the pdc.

Comment: @btw. Good to know, but i thought i would try TIMESOURCE value just in case. I can remmove it, but it didn't work just the same without it beforehand :L

Comment: I still wonder about microsoft's ntp implementation. My cisco devices aren't able to use the ntp server on w2k3 but they use a ntpd on linux just fine. (it may just be down to my screwed up config)

Comment: I guess I will have to have a look at the packet-cap.

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have found. Any suggestions?