# NTP doesn't sync

Tags: windows, ntp, ntpd

I'm using [Meinberg NTP](http://www.meinberg.de/english/sw/ntp.htm) to sync the time in a VPS.
The clock refuses to sync - there's a ~30s shift comparing to other servers. Also 
`ntpq -p` is continuously showing zeros for reach, delays and jitters, which means something's wrong...

Actions I've taken which didn't help:

- Restarted the NTP service using a script that comes with Meinberg NTP
- Added port 123 for UDP and TCP as an exception port to Windows Firewall
- Added Meinberk NTP executables as an exception program to Windows Firewall
- Completely disabled Windows Firewall
- validated `iburst` appears after each server listed in the configuration file
- Restarted the server

The OS is a Windows Server Standard SP2 32bit.

What did I miss?

**UPDATE 1**

Here's `ntpq -p` result:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 voxl-nyc-21.ser .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 sola-sea-04.ser .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 207.32.191.59   .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

**UPDATE 2**
Turns out that in addition to the Windows Firewall, our VPS provider has blocked all UDP communication to our VPS instance. After opening UDP port 123 it worked flawlessly.

Comment: How long did you give it?

Comment: a few minutes...

Comment: That's probably not nearly enough time. Check back in an hour or so.

Comment: Check to see that the windows NTP server is disabled. May I ask why you are not using the inbuilt windows NTP service? (http://serverfault.com/questions/199205/sntp-why-do-you-mock-me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now it seems you're not communicating with your peers. Either they're not up, not reachable, or a firewall or similar device is blocking UDP port 123.

207.32.191.59 appears to be a working stratum 2 server to me, so if the machine otherwise has working Internet access, I'd bet on a firewall.

Comment: David, do you know how I could set it up so that it will sync every 2 minutes? It's critical for our operation to be as time synced as possible to other network servers

Comment: I have `iburst` set in the configuration file, I also restarted the server and it's still ~30s away

Comment: I've synced servers before and their time delta fell immediately to a few milliseconds. AFAIK remaining on 30 seconds this long means something's not working. Also, why would the ntp status give zeros on delays and jitters, that is never true

Comment: by "stats" did you mean `ntpq -p` output? posted...

Comment: I completely disabled the firewall, still no joy